# Get HyperV Memory Size without Elevation

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I need to determine how much memory is used by a certain Hyper-V virtual machine. I am interested in the Startup memory amount. [`Get-VMMemory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/get-vmmemory?view=win10-ps) works, but requires elevation.

It is possible to get the same information using the Hyper-V manager GUI without elavation. Is there a way to get the same information programmatically without elevation?

Answer (score 5):

**Option 1**

Did you try [Exporting the configuration of a virtual machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hyperv_v2/exporting-the-configuration-of-a-virtual-machine) and then read the required parameters from it? That might be helpful for you.

**Option 2**

if you can parse the VM config file located at `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V\Virtual Machines` then you can read startup memory amount.

https://www.itprotoday.com/server-virtualization/reading-binary-vmcx-file-windows-2016-hyper-v

You can set the path of virtual machine [default folder with this](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/56837-change-hyper-v-virtual-machines-default-folder-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Option 1 seems promising, I will give it a try and see if it requires elevation. Option 2 may require elevation, since C:\ProgramData is not always accessible.

Comment: Also for Option 2, if you change the default folder to store Hyper-v machine to something like `D:\Virtual-Machine\` then it may not require elevation. but that would require considerable testing I guess.

Comment: That also depends on the user - I need this to run on computers I can't control.

Comment: It doesn't work without elevation :-( You'll get the bounty since yours is the only answer...